# Share a git repo over LAN

Tags: git, file-sharing

I would like to share some of my work with my colleagues. The whole company uses flavors of Debian Linux and is connected in a LAN network. I don't want to bug the administrator with access to the servers and would just like to leave my PC on, and provide **read** access to anyone interested.

But I can't figure out how to do it. We use `ssh` for authentication and  `gitolite` for authorization.

What was tried:

```
$ sudo adduser guest
$ su guest
$ cd ~
$ git clone somerepo
$ ls -l somerepo
drwxr-xr-x 4 guest guest 4096 Mar 22 14:11 somerepo
```

On a different machine:

```
$ git clone guest@192.168.56.1:somerepo
guest@192.168.56.1's password
```

Comment: so what's the problem with this setup?

Comment: Yes, please [edit] and explain what actually happened. Does this work? If not, how did it fail?

Comment: The problem is that it is asking for a password! When you are cloning someone's repo from GitHub, for example, you don't need to provide any passwords.

Comment: @Vorac that depends on how the repo has been set up. Please [edit] your question and explain that the problem is the password.

Answer (score 1):

The password is probably for ssh, not git. You probably need to set an empty password for guest via

`sudo passwd -d guest`

I would however rather recommend to keep a password that you give to everyone allowed, and encourage them to setup a private / public key for ssh if they want to login without providing a password. This way, you have no open login for everyone (even undesired) on your host. To do so, every one else should use `ssh-keygen` to generate their key if they don't have one, and then

`ssh-copy-id guest@yourhost`

to install their public key on `yourhost` and login without a password. This will add their public key to the file `/home/guest/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `yourhost`